# How to configure index file in CGI server?

Tags: python, server, cgi

I have just made a server (only for localhost) in Python to execute by CGI to execute and try my Python scripts. This is the code of the file that executes the server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()  ## This line enables CGI error reporting

server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8000)
handler.cgi_directories = ["/"]

httpd = server(server_address, handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

When I access some script in the server (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.py`) there is no problem, but when I access the server (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/`) it shows:

```
Error response

Error code 403.

Message: CGI script is not executable ('//').

Error code explanation: 403 = Request forbidden -- authorization will not help.
```

It's like if index files aren't set as default file to access when access a folder instead of a specific file...

I would like to be able to access to `http://127.0.0.1/index.py` when I access `http://127.0.0.1/`. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Python's built-in HTTP server is extremely basic, so it doesn't include such feature. However you can implement it yourself by subclassing `CGIHTTPRequestHandler`, probably replacing the `is_cgi` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `handler.cgi_directories = ["/cgi"]`, you can place an index.html file in "/". And of course, if you want a cgi script index.py as default, you can use the index.html for forwarding...

Answer (score 0):

I did try to modify is_cgi function and it's working!

```
def is_cgi(self):

    collapsed_path = _url_collapse_path(self.path)
    if collapsed_path == '//':
        self.path = '/index.py'
        collapsed_path = _url_collapse_path(self.path)
    dir_sep = collapsed_path.find('/', 1)
    head, tail = collapsed_path[:dir_sep], collapsed_path[dir_sep + 1:]
    if head in self.cgi_directories:
        self.cgi_info = head, tail
        return True
    return False
```

I put this method into this following class:

```
class CGIHandlerOverloadIndex(CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler):
```